# What is the difference between a static library and an archive library?

Tags: c++, c, compiler, libraries, static-linking

In the comments of a [recent answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/369128/149608), I equated a static library with an archive of compiled object files.

The response was that they are not the same, so what is the difference?

To clarify - gcc accepts an archive of object files as a library, as per [Ar_(Unix) #Example_usage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ar_(Unix)#Example_usage).  How does this differ from other forms of static library (if any), and what benefits or negatives are there from using these different library types?

The specific claim was that compiling the source files directly instead of linking with a static library

> will result in faster and better code, especially if you turn on Link Time Optimisation.

and

> You can make an archive of .o files that have been compiled with -flto but those aren't really a static library

however if there are other differences, then I welcome answers addressing those.

Comment: Since "object archive" is a term I think you made up, this question is unanswerable.

Comment: @whatsisname as per [ibm page on ar](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.bpxa500/libarc.htm) _"ar maintains archive libraries. The archive library is a collection of files, typically object files."_

Comment: I looked at the link you posted, which led me [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ar_(Unix)), which led me [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archive_file) which describes an "archive" as something akin to a [Zip file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)).

Comment: A zip of object files is an archive, but isn't useable as a static library AFAIK. Any .a static library is one type of archive, though. Unless the respondee expected a different platform, since you haven't specified one.

Comment: @Useless: Clearly, they're two different things.

Comment: Each apple is different then the next apple. Doesn't make any of them oranges. Yet this is all fruit. I can't say who is right. Can you provide the context this dispute happened in?

Comment: No, one is a superset of the other. A static library is (at least in POSIX-ish environments) one possible type of archive. But there are lots of other archives thar are not at all static libraries.

Comment: @candied_orange see the linked question

Comment: What linked question? Do you just want to know how the file formats of different archives differ? Or how gcc differs in treating archives as static libraries? Or something else?

Comment: @Useless to clear up any confusion on behalf of _any_ party, I'm interested only in what can be used as a static library when compiling/linking, and not any other type of archive

Comment: @Useless specifically, [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/369128/149608) (question linked in the panel on  the right) and how the use of different (static) libraries can affect the compilation/linking process

Comment: So are you really asking about the LTO behaviour, and whether there are similar issues? That's a compiler-specific link-time optimization quality-of-implementation question, and nothing really to do with the archives themselves except that they don't typically contain the original source code.

Comment: Just curious, why the static limitation? Have something against dynamic libraries?

Comment: @RobertHarvey A static library is literally an archive of object files in ar format (which is a different but equally valid format to zip or tar).

Answer (score 6):

A static library is just an `ar` archive (like zip but ancient) of object files. An object file is the source code that has been compiled to machine code, but hasn't been linked yet. You can make a static library like this (on Linux/OSX):

```
# Create a source file containing the single function in our library.
echo "int answer() { return 42; }" > answer.cpp
# Compile it to machine code.
c++ -c answer.cpp -o answer.o
# Compress it into an ar archive.
ar -r libanswer.a answer.o
```

That's it. The `ar` format isn't specific to static libraries at all. You can use it like Zip if you want (but nobody does because it is old and rubbish). There is also one slight improvement you can make which is to add an index to all the symbols in the library which can give a performance improvement when linking. Like this:

```
ar -rs libanswer.a answer.o
```

That's all `ranlib` does if you've ever wondered.

Anyway - the point about Link Time Optimisation is that it doesn't create a "real" object file, in the sense that it doesn't compile to machine code. Take a look:

```
$ c++ -c answer.cpp -o answer.o
$ c++ -c answer.cpp -flto -o answer_lto.o
$ file answer.o
answer.o: Mach-O 64-bit object x86_64
$ file answer_lto.o
answer_lto.o: LLVM bitcode, wrapper x86_64
```

`answer.o` is a native Mach-O object file (because I am on Mac; on Linux it will be ELF). But `answer_lto.o` is not! It's LLVM bitcode. That hasn't been compiled to machine code.

You can put this in an `ar` archive if you want:

```
ar -r libanswer_lto.a answer_lto.o
```

But this isn't a real static library, and no tools (except Clang) will be able to link with it. GCC could link with `libanswer.a` but not with `libanswer_lto.a`.

I guess you *could* call `libanswer_lto.a` a "static library" if you wanted (definitions can change etc.) but if you said "here is a static library" and gave them `libanswer_lto.a` most people would say "what, no it isn't".

I would call it an LLVM bitcode library or something like that.

Comment: You can't use a zip file for linking. It won't work unless you unpack it and manually link the object files.

Comment: No of course not. I didn't say that you could.

Comment: Then why mention `zip` files? They were only asked about in the comments, not the question itself.

Comment: I was explaining what an `ar` archive is. It's like a `zip` file (but a much older format, and without any compression).

Answer (score 1):

They're both the same, and they're both made by `ar`.

An archive of object files (made by `ar rc $object_files` or something similar) is equivalent to other forms of a static library (of which, as far as I know, there are none).

The claim

> that compiling the source files directly instead of linking with a static library will result in faster and better code

is not true. There is no overall effect of linking from a static archive vs. linking against the source/object files directly. In fact, linking object files directly may significantly increase executable size.

The claim

> You can make an archive of .o files that have been compiled with -flto but those aren't really a static library

is not necessarily true. Those object files should work when linked into any program or shared library, and the difference is not obvious as to whether they are regular object files or LTO objects.

Comment: GCC also [does not produce standard object files when using `-flto`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/LTO-object-file-layout.html#LTO-object-file-layout). They *are* in ELF format, but they just have sections containing GCC IR, exactly like LLVM does. You couldn't link them with Clang.

Comment: You cannot link with a static library (i.e. an archive of fully-compiled object files) if you want to use LTO. LTO needs access to the GCC IR, or LLVM bitcode.